# Duplicate records removal by access max id

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates, max

sorry to ask you but i can't seem to comeup with good solution, i've done research online but with my limited experience in this i can't seemed to figure out what i am doing wrong.
i have over 600000 records that have duplicates and i need duplicates removed based on the max id number because records have many other fields that are not exactly duplicates therefore i am having a hard time figuring out. Please help.

sample attached

[image]

i need it to look like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE
FROM yourtable AS a
WHERE a.id NOT IN
(
SELECT Max(b.id)
FROM yourtable AS b
WHERE a.field1 = b.field1
)
```

With the subquery you select the maximum id for each value of field1.
The delete statement will then delete all records per value of field1 where the id does not equal the maximum id vale.

Comment: yours worked really good, just trying to understand the reasoning behind yourtable as a and yourtable as b. So we're creating virtual tables and both comparing if duplicate but not max than delete.

Comment: It's not virtual tables but a query (delete bla bla) which contains a subquery. Both queries refer to one and the same table. Now if you want to compare data within one table, which we do using the WHERE clause in the subquery), you should use aliases. Otherwise you simply can't compare data within that same table. I'd suggest to read up upon SELF JOINS.

Answer (score 1):

So what you and your example are saying is that a row should be deleted if there exists another row with equal FIELD1 and a greater ID. That sentence translated into SQL becomes:

```
delete from my_table m where exists
(select 1 from my_table where field1=m.field1 and id>m.id);
```

Another way is to delete every row that are not among the ones with max(id) for each distinct value in field1:

```
delete from my_table where (field1,id) not in
(select field1, max(id) from my_table group by field1);
```

I'm not sure which of the two are easier to read.

Comment: i am getting an error message with this sql "You have written a subquery that can return more than one field without using the EXISTS reserved word in the main query's FROM clause"

sql i have: 
delete *
from dupcombination2 
where (field1,id) not in
(select field1, max(id) 
from dupcombination2 
group by field1);

Comment: just tried your first method worked but the second didn't. just fyi.

Comment: Ok, not all databases support multi valued IN or NOT IN then I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 Delete from table where ID NOT IN
 (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TABLE GROUP BY  filed1, filed2, filed3 , sourcetable)
```

Comment: tried this, and it says, you're about to delete 0 records and does not remove duplicates
Delete * 
from dupcombination2
 where ID NOT IN
 (SELECT MAX(ID) 
FROM dupcombination2 
GROUP BY  field1, field2, field3 , sourcetable)